# Using the NorthWind database, write the SQL statement that reports each employees name and any orders that were taken by that employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to learn about the outer join queries and I can't figure out exactly how to word them. This is what I have but it shows the same results as just a regular join so there must be something I'm not picking up.

```
SELECT 
    Employees.FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS EmployeeName, 
    Orders.OrderID AS Orders
FROM 
    Employees
RIGHT JOIN 
    Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

If an outer join (`LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`) resembles an inner join, then all records match between the two tables per the `ON` conditions. In other words, there are  no *outer* records.

Consider further review:

- Can an order exist without an employee? Check if `ORDERS` maintains a foreign key constraint to `EMPLOYEES`. Being a one-to-many relationship where an employee can have multiple orders, Northwind possibly imposes referential integrity between the tables (similar to Customers-Orders), disallowing mismatches. For this, check the `ORDERS` table definition.
- If no foreign key constraint exists and so `EmployeeID` may be an optional field usually but not always populated, check for `NULL` which would not emerge in your current query but can in `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

  ```
  SELECT OrderID
  FROM ORDERS 
  WHERE EmployeeID IS NULL
  ```
- Also, if no foreign key constraint exists, orphaned or legacy records may exist where an employee was deleted from `EMPLOYEES` table but his/her corresponding `ORDERS` remain. For this, your outer join query should return *more* rows than inner join where employee fields will result with `NULL` but order fields with non-`NULL` values. Hence, check this non-match with `WHERE` condition:

  ```
  SELECT e.FirstName +' '+ e.LastName as EmployeeName
       , o.OrderID as Orders
  FROM Employees e
  RIGHT JOIN Orders o
    ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
  WHERE e.EmployeeID IS NULL
  ```
- Maybe you want to check employees with no orders (which does not violate foreign key constraint)? For this, reverse the operation with `LEFT JOIN`, then check mismatches also on the outer table:

  ```
  SELECT e.FirstName +' '+ e.LastName as EmployeeName
       , o.OrderID as Orders
  FROM Employees e
  LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
  WHERE o.EmployeeID IS NULL
  ```